# Get system audio output stream from kernel extension - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audio, core-audio

I want to get system audio output stream from kernel extension like SoundFlower.
But I am new about System Kernel extension.

At this point, I got SoundFlower Output device from output devices.
I need to know how to get audio stream from the output device.
Stream result should be byte array.

I've looked through the Core Audio and AVFoundation documentation, but I can't seem to find a way to get to the system audio.

Thanks in advance.